# setting mime type to json,still i am receive response in html while hosting an application on IIS 7.0

Tags: json, iis, iis-express

I am not getting correct response while deploying an application on iis. On local machine, I was getting **json/application** as a content type but while hosting an application on iis7.0, I am getting **text/html** as a content type.

I set MIME type in IIS to json/application, 
here is the step for setting MIME type to json.

**File name extension: .json
MIME type: application/json**

But still i am not getting correct response.

What should i do?? Hope you all can solve my problem.
Thanks

Comment: Where did you add mime type entry? At website or application level? Also did you restart iis or apppool after adding mime type?

Comment: at application level..ya i restarted iis..